# Error in Running Kafka in Windows : No security protocol defined for listener HTTP

Tags: apache-kafka

Using the following link I have tried running kafka in windows [Setting Up and Running Apache Kafka on Windows OS](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os)

I am able to run the zookeeper without any errors and when I try to run the command

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

I am getting the following error

```
 ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners
 from 'http://localhost:9092': No security protocol defined for
 listener HTTP
         at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.listenerListToEndPoints(CoreUtils.scala:312)
         at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.advertisedListeners(KafkaConfig.scala:1334)
         at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1396)
         at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1374)
         at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1063)
         at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1043)
         at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
         at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:59)
         at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Please direct me in resolving the above issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the errors stated by doing the following things

1. I reinstalled Kafka
2. I made sure that my environmental path for Java is pointing to a 64 but VM only.